# How to use a data bound variable in a filter in ng-repeat (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

```
<!-- Left Navbar -->
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 50px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul ng-repeat="type in types" class="nav nav-sidebar">

            <li>{{type}}</li>                
            <li ng-repeat="sensor in sensors | filter: { type: {{type}} }"><a href="#">{{sensor.name}}</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to nest a ng-repeat and would like to use the value of the outer repeat to determine the inner repeat. I would like to dynamically build a navigation bar to list all items in a json array of objects and list them under their sensor type (led, fan, motor, ect) Is this possible?

I have a scope variable sensors with all the sensors on the board and a types array that has all the distinct types of sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data structure is defined as this

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.types = [
        "A", "B"
    ];

    $scope.sensors = [{
        "type": "A",
            "name": "AA"
    }, {
        "type": "B",
            "name": "BB"
    }];
}
```

Use this syntax:

```
ng-repeat="sensor in sensors | filter: {'type': type}"
```